# Is there a more compact way of writing these identical conditionals?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to check that the type of four variables is a particular type, and I have to do:

```
if (type(a) is not SomeType or
    type(b) is not SomeType or
    type(c) is not SomeType or
    type(d) is not SomeType):
    raise Exception("Not the correct types")
```

This feels repetitive. It seems there could be a better, less redundant way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to check if any of the items are of type `SomeType`.

You should also consider using [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check for types.

```
if any(not isinstance(item, SomeType) for item in [a,b,c,d]):
    raise Exception("Not the correct types")
```

You can also write this using [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

```
if not all(isinstance(item, SomeType) for item in [a,b,c,d]):
    raise Exception("Not the correct types")
```

Comment: The parameters to `isinstance` are backwards, and in addition it should be `any(not ...)`. Also note that `type(x) is A` is not exactly the same as `instance(x, A)` as the latter also allows derived types (though `isinstance` is usually better).

Comment: For me this is more readable: `if not all(isinstance(item, SomeType) for item in [a,b,c,d]):`